# Serialize OneToMany relation into array in Django

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have some django models:

```
class Restaurant(Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=200)

class Food(Model):
    restaurant = ForeignKey(Restaurant, on_delete=CASCADE)
    name = CharField(max_length=200)
```

One Restaurant can have multiple foods.

And I want my json to look like this:

```
[
    {
        "name": "xxx",
        "food": [{"name": "xxx"}, {"name": "xxx"}, ...]
    }, ...
]
```

I can use something like:

```
restaurants = Restaurant.objects.all().values()
for restaurant in restaurants:
    restaurant['food'] = Food.objects.filter(restaurant__id=restaurant['id']).values()
```

But this loses some optimization in SQL level, as this is using application level loop.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Yes. Use django-rest-framework which supports this kind of serialization directly.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Could you provide an example or a link on this functionality? I have taken a look at the docs but cannot find it right away.

Comment: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
restaurant = Restaurant.objects.all()
result = []
for rest in restaurant:
    data = {
            'name': rest.name,
            'food': rest.food_set.all().values('name')
           }
    result.appen(data)
```

Try it....

User django rest framework. using serialzers you can do it more effectively

Answer (score -1):

@Nakamura You are correct, query inside the loop is not a good way of coding.
below is one way of solving

```
restaurants = Restaurant.objects.all().values()
foods = Food.objects.all()
for restaurant in restaurants:
    restaurant['food'] = foods.filter(restaurant__id=restaurant['id']).values()
```

As you gave required JSON format i suggested this answer.

Comment: This is exactly the same.

Comment: Nope query happens only one time. It more efficient than that

Comment: Query to DB will be only on fist iteration , foods.filter() in the further iterations foods variable has values that will be used

Comment: No. That is not true.